# Azure usageDetails REST API - Cannot filter on tags

Tags: azure, api, rest, postman

I am using PostMan to make a GET callout to Azure's REST API. According to their [API Docs on usageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list), you can use the `$filter` query parameter to filter on tags like this: `tags eq 'Project ID:PR-008016'`. I triple checked that the tags exist in Azure and they are correct, but when I use that in the `$filter` param, I get a 200 response but it returns an empty `values` array.

For context, this `$filter` parameter will return data and filter correctly:

`$filter=properties/usageStart eq '2020-07-22' and properties/usageEnd eq '2020-08-01'`

But when I add the `tags` filter, it returns the blank `values` array:

`$filter=properties/usageStart eq '2020-07-22' and properties/usageEnd eq '2020-08-01' and tags eq 'Project ID:PR-008016'`

**Does anyone know if the syntax is incorrect? Or if there is possibly a bug with the Azure REST Api?** ([this comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38660#issuecomment-664642354) suggest there may be a product bug)

**Full Endpoint:**

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01&$filter=properties/usageStart eq '2020-07-22' and properties/usageEnd eq '2020-08-01' and tags eq 'Project ID:PR-008016'`

Comment: I think i found the reason they weren't showing up. usageDetails data is only available via the REST api if the tag was applied BEFORE the usageDetails data was created in Azure. Details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/announcing-the-support-for-tags-in-cost-management-apis/

Comment: I have summarized it as a reply. You can accept it as answer to helps others who have same problem.

Comment: @Tom were you able to actually use this ? Once I provide the thag filter the result is always empty for me. `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2021-10-01&$filter=tags eq 'Vendor:Databricks'  and properties/usageStart ge '2022-11-01' and properties/usageEnd le '2022-11-10'`

Comment: @DoruChiulan yes it was a while ago but i think tthe filter I listed worked for me. Maybe try putting usageStart and usageEnd before the tags filter? Make sure you read the documentation very carefully, the syntax has to be perfect for this api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have pointed that, **the support for tags is not retroactive and will only apply to usage reported after the tag was applied to the resource**. Tag based filtering and aggregation is supported by the `$filter` and `$apply` parameters respectively.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/announcing-the-support-for-tags-in-cost-management-apis/).

Comment: can you please give example of how to pass tags filter. i tried below one
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<test subs>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=tags eq 'application:app2'&api-version=2021-10-01` and not working for me. i want to get all resources usage data for specific application with specific time period.

Comment: "will only apply to usage reported after the tag was applied to the resource" What do you exactly mean by this ? I have costs generated by databrics, the tags are specified in databricks even before any resource is created  (e.g job clusters), however once I specify any tag filter I get back empty results. Is there anything more fancy about applying tags ?

Comment: @DoruChiulan For example, if an Azure resource is created on Jan. 1 without a tag. Then on Jan 5, a tag is added, then on Jan 7 if you use the api to get all of the ussageDetail data for the last 30 days, the usageDetail data from Jan 1 WOULD NOT be included, because the tag didn't exist on that resource on Jan. 1. You said you have tags in databricks, but have you applied the appropriate tag to the Azure resource in Azure itself?

Comment: they are automatically applied to resources created by that databricks instances, I can see them in the usage details when I'm not using the tag filter. Anyway, I was able to achieve something close to what I wanted using filtering by resourceGroup. Anyway that API and documentation is a joke